# done is not a function in passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (req, username, password, done) => {
            User.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, user) => {

                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown user
                    else if (!user)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!user.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password.' });
                    // wrong type
                    else if (!user.verifyType(req.body.type))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong type.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, user);
                });
        })
);
```

done is not a function is the error
Using PassportJS, how pass one additional form fields to the local authentication strategy?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/), there is no `req` argument.

Comment: yes then how to use another patameter for authentication

Comment: Is `req` really the request object? In other words, does it contain `req.body`? Not sure yet how to use other parameters

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "req" parameter in the anonymous function inside new localStrategy and you should be fine.

You don't have the req parameter anywhere on this code, so you can't use it in there

like this:

```
 (username, password, done) => {
```

Comment: I use it to check the type I won't to add a another parameter

Comment: You are not sending the "req" as parameter, you are expecting to receive it, but the localStrategy doesnt have it, so you are tryng to use a parameter that doesnt exist.

Comment: pass it when you call the passport.authenticate like this
passport.authenticate('local', 'yourParameter', function(err, user, info) {
   // Do what you have to do
});

Comment: thanks but then how to pass that parameter to above function

Comment: posted as new answer because the code is too long for a comment XD

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        yourParameter
        (req, username, password, done) => {
            User.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, user) => {

                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown user
                    else if (!user)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!user.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password.' });
                    // wrong type
                    else if (!user.verifyType(yourParameter))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong type.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, user);
                });
        })
);
```

Comment: thanks but then above function not return anything if i give wrong email it return {}